# Как вывести в файл данные с запроса?

Tags: java

```
static void fileWriter(Request request) throws IOException {

    try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("information.txt")) {

        writer.write(request.toString());
        //Need a new line in the file each time the method is called!
    }
```

- При выводе получаю всё в одну строку, как перейти на новую строку во время вывода в файл?
- Вывод содержит данные об ip, host, port, буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно получить все параметры реквеста и формировать строки **Параметр-Значение**.

```
Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames(); 
while(params.hasMoreElements()) {
   String param = (String) params.nextElement();
   writer.write(param + ": " + request.getParameter(param) + ";" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try(Writer writer = new FileWriter("information.txt",true)){

        writer.write(request.toString());
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        writer.close();
```

- Еще вариант!